# How to filter DBpedia results in SPARQL

Tags: java, sparql, jena, dbpedia

I have a little problem...
if I have this simple SPARQL query

```
SELECT ?abstract 
WHERE {
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mitsubishi> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract> ?abstract.
FILTER langMatches( lang(?abstract), 'en')}
```

I have this result:
[SPARQL Result](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20%3Fabstract%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FMitsubishi%3E%0D%0A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Fabstract%3E%20%3Fabstract.%20%0D%0AFILTER%20langMatches%28%20lang%28%3Fabstract%29%2C%20%27en%27%29%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)
and it has a non-English character...
is there any idea how to remove them and retrieve just English words?

Comment: Could you explain why exactly do you want to do that? What should happen if the non-English word is part of a sentence?

Comment: I'm trying to integrate the results with another text using FF extension.the non English character cause some problem with Java script coding the FF extension

Comment: That sounds like you should figure out what the actual problem is and fix it, not trying to work around it like this. JavaScript should be able to handle Unicode just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to define exactly what characters you want and don't want in your result, but you can use **replace** to replace characters outside of a range with, e.g., empty strings.  If you wanted to exclude all but the Basic Latin, Latin-1 Supplement, Latin Extended-A, and Latin Extended-B ranges, (which ends up being \u0000–\u024f) you could do the following:

```sql
SELECT ?abstract ?cleanAbstract
WHERE {
  dbpedia:Mitsubishi dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract 
  FILTER langMatches( lang(?abstract), 'en')
  bind(replace(?abstract,"[^\\x{0000}-\\x{024f}]","") as ?cleanAbstract)
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20%3Fabstract%20%3FcleanAbstract%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3AMitsubishi%20dbpedia-owl%3Aabstract%20%3Fabstract%20%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20langMatches%28%20lang%28%3Fabstract%29%2C%20%27en%27%29%0D%0A%20%20bind%28replace%28%3Fabstract%2Cconcat%28%22[%5E%20-~]%22%29%2C%22%22%29%20as%20%3FcleanAbstract%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Or even simpler:

```sql
SELECT (replace(?abstract_,"[^\\x{0000}-\\x{024f}]","") as ?abstract)
WHERE {
  dbpedia:Mitsubishi dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract_
  FILTER langMatches(lang(?abstract_), 'en')
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20%28replace%28%3Fabstract_%2C%22[%5E%20-~]%22%2C%22%22%29%20as%20%3Fabstract%29%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3AMitsubishi%20dbpedia-owl%3Aabstract%20%3Fabstract_%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Fabstract_%29%2C%20%27en%27%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

> The Mitsubishi Group (, Mitsubishi Gurūpu) (also known as the
>   Mitsubishi Group of Companies or Mitsubishi Companies) is a group of
>   autonomous Japanese multinational companies covering a range of
>   businesses which share the Mitsubishi brand, trademark, and legacy.The
>   Mitsubishi group of companies form a loose entity, the Mitsubishi
>   Keiretsu, which is often referenced in Japanese and US media and
>   official reports; in general these companies all descend from the
>   zaibatsu of the same name. The top 25 companies are also members of
>   the Mitsubishi Kin'yōkai, or "Friday Club", and meet monthly. In
>   addition the Mitsubishi.com Committee exists to facilitate
>   communication and access of the Mitsubishi brand through a portal web
>   site.

You may find the [Latin script in Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script_in_Unicode) Wikipedia article useful.

Comment: sounds great.. I'll try it and let you know if it works for me
thanks alot

Comment: I try i,but still I have a problem with non English word like  (Kin'yōkai)

Comment: well, that's a pronunciation guide, really; so I wouldn't really call it a "non-English word".  That said, you can change the regex to `\\x{0000}-\\x{00ff}` and then you'll have only ASCII characters.  But all this is about **characters**;  you don't have a way to detect whether the **words** are English or not.  After all, you still want "Mitsubishi" right? And "zaibatsu" too?  Those are both non-English words.